# Ambigious reference to member request() issues with Alamofire after migration to swift 3

Tags: swift, alamofire, swift3, xcode8

So I am new to swift as a whole so bear with me.. I had the query working in swift 2 but after I migrated to swift 3 I get the error

> Ambiguous reference to member 'request(_:withMethod:parameters:encoding:headers:)'

Below is the code in which it occurs:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, serverRequest).validate().responseJSON( { response in
        switch response.result{
        case .Success:
            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                let final = JSON[wantedClass] as! String//forces output to string
                self.failure("You asked what your " + wantedClass + " is, it is:", message: final)
            }
        case .Failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
})
```

I am at a loss of what is the problem.

Comment: I tried that and it did not change anything. Thanks though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have Alamofire `swift3` branch working in Xcode 8.0 ß6 with the following code:

```
Alamofire.request("https://\(ip)/api/version", withMethod: .get, 
    parameters: nil, encoding: .json, headers: headers)
            .validate()
            .responseJSON { response in
                //debugPrint(response)
                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    if let JSON = response.result.value {
                        let version = Mapper<Version>().map(JSON)
                        print("Version \(version?.server!)")
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print (error)
                }
            }
```

Pay close attention to the order and types of your arguments to `.request`

You should have only one Alamofire framework active. Try to redo it in another clone, or maybe try the following in the clone you have?

```
pod cache clean --all
pod install
```

What does your `Podfile` have in it?

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'NewApp' do
    pod 'Alamofire', 
        :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git',
        :branch => 'swift3'
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem - they reordered parameters in the method, so now '.get' should be placed after **withMethod**.

If you use Alamofire 4.0 in your project (I assume you do, because this error I got on version 4) you need to write

```
Alamofire.request(serverRequest, withMethod: .get)
```

or for example

```
Alamofire.request(serverRequest, withMethod: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: .url, headers: nil)
```

Comment: If you want to use Alamofire 4, in this time of Aug 19, you need to set your minimum deployment target to 9.0, and in your Podfile you need to provide the swift3 branch that is not officially released. The will do after Apple releases GM seed.

Comment: For some reason that did not work.  The error does go away however if there is no response handling done. But that doesn't really help because I need the response.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot with the error and code diplayed, in xcode?

Comment: Have you tried to 1. clean the build folder? 2. start typing the function so IDE will suggest you possibilities? I hope you have Alamofire 4.0, otherwise this code will not work either. Please add one more screen as the error on your image is not fully displayed

Comment: 1. As in clean the project before building it? Just tried and nothing changed.  2.  Even with using the function the IDE suggests it still gives the same error.
I am using Alamofire 4.0  [link](http://imgur.com/gallery/QzRLV)

Comment: 1. Try to clean build folder clicking on Product -> Clean build folder... (after you click CMD you'll see different menu item. How is your serverRequest defined?

Comment: The cleaning build folder did not work. I have had it both as a string but now it is 
var serverRequest = URLRequest(method: .get, urlString: "http://192.168.0.25:3000/" + wantedClass)

Comment: I have written the request directly as string, and it works. Like this: Alamofire.request("http: // example.com/xxx/xxx", args...)

Comment: well I think I figured it out.  I put in the string like you said but I was missing .response at the end so it was having issues with the response.  Thank you!!!

Comment: Cool, glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using swift 5

and your entry is like this

```
import Alamofire

class AlamofireNetworkRequest {
    static func sendRequest(url: String) {
        guard let url = URL(string: url) else { return }
        .request(url).responseJSON { (response) in
            print(response)
        }
    }
}
```

add AF before .request

like this

```
AF.request(url).responseJSON { (response) in
```