# Swift 3 Compiling Error with Alamofire

Tags: alamofire, swift3, xcode8-beta6

I seem to be having a problem with "Alamofire" being recognized.  I have cleaned and then built. sometimes it will recognize it for a few seconds, but then will not.  I have looked at past comments, and changed the syntax within the ( ), but that is not the problem.  The problem is the Alamofire.  When I start to type, the only option I get is AlamofireVersionNumber.  I did import Alamofire, so that is not the issue.  I am at a loss.  I am running Xcode 8 Beta 6.

[image]

Comment: Hi Darell, try to check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39029890/ambigious-reference-to-member-request-issues-with-alamofire-after-migration-to/39032301#39032301. Hope it helps, or other ones. Alamofire version number   was also the only hint for me. Try to type 'Alamofire.request(' and you should see suggestion, or clean the build folder and restart Xcode too.

Comment: If you need to update latest Alamofire version to 4.0, check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39052408/661022